# Passing JSON data in pattern | PatternLab

Tags: javascript, mustache, patternlab.io

I want to include an atomic pattern and want to pass data from a JSON array below is code and JSON file.

**anchor-link.mustache**

```
<a href="{{ url }}" class="{{ class }}">{{ label }}</a>
```

**footer-nav.mustache**

```
<ul class="menu vertical">
{{# footerNav }}
    <li>{{> atoms-anchor-link(url:url, label : label, class : class) }}</li>
{{/ footerNav }}
</ul>
```

**JSON from where i want to populate anchor mustache**

```
{
    "footerNav": [{
        "label": "Shop",
        "url": "#",
        "class": "body-copy"
    }, {
        "label": "Pods",
        "url": "#",
        "class": "all-caps-large"
    }]
}
```

**Output**

```
<ul class="menu vertical">
    <li><a href="" class=""></a>
</li>
    <li><a href="" class=""></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Pattern Lab is generating correct HTML and creates anchors but no values are populating in anchors.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have called wrong pattern here.

```
<li>{{> atoms-anchor-link(url:url, label : label, class : class) }}</li>
```

Correct pattern is.

```
<li>{{> atoms-anchor-link}}</li>
```

This will work.